# Using php condition and javascript hide the div's

Tags: php, jquery, html

I just messed up with is a problem from the last couple of hours and still didn't get the solution i m new in php.what I m trying to do is display and hide the dive according to php condition.
here is the scenario:

**note: by default DIV(display:none)**

**if(condition is satisfied )** //condition in PHP only

//call the javascript function which displays the div

**else**

//call the javascript function which hides the div

if you have the solution with example please must share it's a humble request
thank you

Comment: why not php only `if(condition is true){div display block}else{div display none;}`.

Comment: bcz i want to satisfied the condition which fetches from db

Comment: then also do it with php? where is jquery coming into picture for that, and what intelligent match you gona do with jQuery based on whichh you are going to do stuff?

Comment: [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Comment: You might find this informative: [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You want to mix Java*script*, HTML and CSS as little as possible. It might look easier to mix it right now, but that will change as you get more experience.

There are multiple ways, but one I prefer is running PHP and passing the variables to a JS variable and let JS decide:

```
const showSpecificElement = <?php echo funtionWhichDoesSomething(); ?>;
if( showSpecificElement ){
    // Javascript magic here
}

// Or, alternatively:
if(<?php echo funtionWhichDoesSomething(); ?>){
    // Javascript magic here
}

// Or, slightly better:
$classWhichHidesThisDivOrNot =  rand(1,2)==1 ? 'hideMe' : 'showMe';
<div class="<?=$classWhichHidesThisDivOrNot?>"> ... </div>
```